# Sets/Groups and inverse?

Tags: group-theory

"If $x * y = 5xy$ then the inverse of $2$ w.r.t to the group operation $*$ is ____?"

I have no idea on how to go about doing this question.... does it mean a multiplicative inverse of that equation or something?

Can somebody please explain this to me like I'm a complete idiot. The q is a MCQ and the final answer is $1/50$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that an element $a$ is called inverse of $b$ (with respect to the operation $\ast$) when $a\ast b=b \ast a=e$ where $e$ is the neutral element.

Thus first of all you need to figure out what $e$ is or if it even exists.

Is there an element $e$ such that $x\ast e = e\ast x = x$ for every $x$.

You'll find that yes there is one and it is $1/5$ because $x\ast 1/5 = 5 x (1/5)=x$.

Having found that it remains to solve $2  \ast x = 1/5$ that is $5(2 x) = 1/5  $, which is your result.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is allowed here but can you tell me this topics (sub-)name or link me to a online tutorial with more problems like this?

Comment: It would be allowed but I am sorry I do not have any good reference for this type of problems specifically. "binary operations" could  be a relevant search term.

Answer (score 2):

Your goal in this problem is to simply substitute in definitions, with the goal of converting the given question to one or more algebra problems.

For example, the definition of "inverse of $2$ with respect to $*$" is

> $x$ is the inverse of $2$ with respect to $*$ if and only if $2 * x = i$ and $x * 2 = i$, where $i$ the identity for $*$

Similarly, when you see the equation $2 * x = i$, you can simply substitute in the definition of $*$ to get $5 \cdot 2 \cdot x = i$, and similarly for other equations.

Note that you need to know what the identity is. That's a separate problem you can solve: i.e. you want to solve the following exercise:

> Find the identity element for $*$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find the identity element with respect to $*$ first. Then you will be able to find the inverse easily.

Comment: Isn't a identity element w.r.t * equal to 1?

Comment: $*$ is just a binary operation defined by $x*y:=5xy$ where on the right hand side you have the standard multiplication.